# Using C library in mirageos

Tags: ocaml, ctypes, mirage

I need to do U2F in a mirageos project, and as far as I can tell there are no ocaml implementations of it.
I've read [this article on the blog](https://mirage.io/blog/modular-foreign-function-bindings) and it sounds like it should be possible to use the C library provided by yubico for this, but the article doesn't really explain how to even compile that in mirage, unfortunately.

Is anyone aware of a mirage project I could take a look at, to see how it works, or an article explaining it ?